# Find a Rust enum variant name from a GDB-Python Value

Tags: rust, gdb, gdb-python

Rust recently introduced [`#![debugger_visualizer(gdb_script_file = "...")]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/reference/attributes/debugger.html) to allow embedding GDB pretty-printers in libraries.

I'm playing around with this feature, with not that much knowledge in GDB pretty-printers in the first place, and I'm stuck trying to figure out which variant of an `enum` is active.

[The docs](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Types-In-Python.html) mention a property `Type.dynamic` that tells if a GDB-Python `Type` value represents an `enum` type (among other type kinds), but there's no other mention on how to actually know which variant of a value is active. Printing the `Value` value actually prints the full type with variant (e.g. `core::option::Option<i32>::Some`), but I haven't found a "clean" way to get this information without resorting to string parsing.

How can I get an Rust `enum`'s variant name from GDB-Python `Value`?